# Get radio button value onload and hide or show div

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have the following jsfiddle setup:

http://jsfiddle.net/cvn6n/

Based on the radio selection a div is hidden or displayed (if audi is selected the div is hidden and if any other value is selected the div is displayed). The problem that I have is that I need to detect the initial value (onload) of the radio button and accordingly hide or display the div.

```
Audi <input type="radio" name="car" id="audi" value="3" checked="checked" onclick="toggle(this)">
<br />
Merc <input type="radio" name="car" id="merc" value="3" onclick="toggle(this)">
<br />
BMW <input type="radio" name="car" id="bmw" value="3" onclick="toggle(this)">
<br /><br />
<div id="testdiv">
Not Audi
</div>

var t = document.getElementById('testdiv');

t.style.visibility = 'visible';                
function toggle(switchElement) {
    if (switchElement.id != 'audi'){
        t.style.display = 'inline';
    }else{
        t.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

ps. no jquery please just pure js solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[].forEach.call( document.forms.carform.car, function(radio){
      if( radio.checked ) {
          toggle( radio );   
      }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cvn6n/1/

Answer (score 0):

From your example, noticed I moved the active value to Merc, also notice you should set display: none on your testdiv when you initialize it:

```
Audi <input type="radio" name="car" id="audi" value="3" onclick="toggle(this)">
<br />
Merc <input type="radio" name="car" id="merc" value="3" checked="checked" onclick="toggle(this)">
<br />
BMW <input type="radio" name="car" id="bmw" value="3" onclick="toggle(this)">
<br /><br />
<div id="testdiv" style="display:none;">
Not Audi
</div>
```

For the javascript, you can put the section I added to window.onload or at the bottom of your page, so it fires after the DOM has finished loading.  Basically, it goes through the list of provided ids to check, and sets toggle() for the active one.

```
var t = document.getElementById('testdiv');

t.style.visibility = 'visible';                
function toggle(switchElement) {
    if (switchElement.id != 'audi') {
        t.style.display = 'inline';
    }else{
        t.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

var listOfIds = new Array("audi", "merc", "bmw");
for (x in listOfIds) {
    var element = document.getElementById(listOfIds[x]);
    if (element.checked) {
        toggle(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I have decided to go with @Esailija solution instead purely because building an array of id's is just an additional overhead as the car brands are not fixed and will vary. But much appreciated and will bare this solution in mind :)